# Is it possible to access elasticsearch's internal stats via Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I can see from querying our elasticsearch nodes that they contains internal statistics that for example show disk, memory and CPU usage (for example via GET _nodes/stats API).

Is there anyway to access these in Kibana-4?

Comment: Pay for support and use Marvel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, as ElasticSearch doesn't natively push it's internal statistics to an index.  However you could easily set something like this up on a *nix box:

1. Poll your ElasticSearch box via REST periodically (say, once a minute). The `/_status` or `/_cluster/health` end points probably contain what you're after.
2. Pipe these to a log file in a simple CSV format along with a time stamp.
3. Point logstash to these log files and forward the output to your ElasticSearch box.
4. Graph your data.

Comment: Thanks Luke - suspected it was going to be something like that.

Comment: Instead of using CSV log files/logstash, you can simply post data to Elasticsearch via REST (given that you will use REST to query it anyway)